# How to add and then edit UITableViewCell without another view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview

I know I can't directly edit a UITableViewCell, that is, I have to somehow embed a UITextField in it. I get that. But here's what I want to do, if possible.

I have a table view controller with "Edit" on the left and "+" on the right on its navigation bar. I want to do this...

1. When I tap the "+" button, I want a custom UITableViewCell with an embedded UITextField to be added the table view. (I know how to create the custom cell.)
2. After the cell is added, I want the table view to enter into editting mode, where the "Edit" turns to "Done" on navigation bar.
3. Now I can tap inside the cell, a keyboard appears, I type what I want, press "Done" and voila, I have the cell with my typed entry.

How can I accomplish #1 and #2? Can this be done? Any examples online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. This works. Just create the appropriate UITableViewController in Storyboards and make the appropriate connections. I can include the project file if you can't get it to work.

If any of this doesn't make sense, please comment. Happy coding!

```
//BGSMainTableViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BGSMainTableViewController : UITableViewController

@end

//BGSMainTableViewController.m

#import "BGSMainTableViewController.h"
#import "BGSTextCell.h"

@interface BGSMainTableViewController () {
    NSArray *tableObjects;
}

@end

@implementation BGSMainTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set objects
    tableObjects = @[@"Object1", @"Object2", @"Object3"];

    // Set edit button
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    // Set add button
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
           initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
                                target:self 
                                action:@selector(addObject)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableObjects count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    BGSTextCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textView.text = [tableObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // So the user can't edit the cell while not in "editing mode"
    [cell.textView setEditable:NO];

    return cell;
}

-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if(editing)
    { 
        // Code here executed when "Edit" button pushed
        NSLog(@"editing");
        // You can go back here and turn on editing for each cell so the user can edit
        // all the cells. You just have to add more code below to update all the entries 
        // in the tableObjects array
    }
    else
    {
        // Code executed here when "Done" button is pushed

        // indexPath for recently added cell
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1 inSection:0];

        // This gets our newly added cell. We have to typecast it in order to avoid 
        // warnings and use the properties we've set up in the BGSTextCell .h/.m file 
        //In this case, the UITextView
        BGSTextCell *cell = (BGSTextCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tableObjects];

        if ([cell.textView.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            // If cell is empty, delete it
            [newArray removeLastObject];
            tableObjects = [NSArray arrayWithArray:newArray];
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            // If cell contains text, add it to objects array, but replace the dummy 
            // string we added in addObject
            [newArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[newArray count] - 1 withObject:cell.textView.text];
            tableObjects = [NSArray arrayWithArray:newArray];

            // reset textview to not allow editing 
            cell.textView.editable = NO;
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - Accessory Methods

- (void)addObject
{
    // 1 - Add a dummy string object to the array that the tableview receive's its data 
    // from. This has to be done first or there won't be data for the added 
    // UITableViewCell and an exception will be thrown.
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tableObjects];
    [newArray addObject:@""];
    tableObjects = [NSArray arrayWithArray:newArray];

    // 2 - Add cell to the last position in the tableView    
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

    // 3 - Get the newly added cell and allow editing
    BGSTextCell *addedCell = (BGSTextCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [addedCell.textView setEditable:YES];

    // 4 - This is what automatically pulls up the keyboard
    [addedCell.textView becomeFirstResponder];

    // 5 - Puts the tableView in "editing mode"
    self.editing = YES;
}

// BGSTextCell.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BGSTextCell : UITableViewCell

// I'm using a UITextView and NOT a UITextField because it's a lot easier to prevent 
// editing by just assigning NO to setEditable: . Someone can correct me on this, but I    
// personally haven't found an easy way to prevent editing on a UITextField
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;

@end


// BGSTextCell.m
#import "BGSTextCell.h"

@implementation BGSTextCell

@end
```

Comment: added some comments to the code to make it easier to understand. Hope it helps!

Comment: I actually made it work with a text field. I just made the custom cell a UITextField delegate, and sent [cell.textField becomeFirstResponder] and [cell.textField resignFirstResponder] to enter/exit edit mode respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
      self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
      UIBarButtonItem *addItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(whenAddButtonTapped:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addItem;
  }

  - (void)whenAddButtonTapped:(id)sender
  {
    //logic to load datasource
    int count = [array count];
     count ++;
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];
    [array addObject:str];
    [self.aTableView reloadData];//add the cell

    //after change the edit to done
    self.aTableView.editing = YES;//make the tableview to editing mode
    [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];//set the button done

  }

 //u need to implement this to change the beheaviour of edit button
 - (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
 {
     [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
     if(editing)
    {
      self.aTableView.editing = editing;

    }
    else
    {
      self.aTableView.editing = NO;
   }

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get idea of adding cell on add button taped by using default/template project - Master-Detail Application

Identifier can be set as - select the connection - move to Attribute inspector panel

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Your first Controller"])
{

}
else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Your second Controller"])
{

}
```

See the below pic for more details
[image: How add and edit with one controller]

Comment: I clarified my post. Your answer did not make sense but perhaps because my post was vague.

Comment: @ChrisF You can get idea of adding cell on add button taped by using default/template project - Master-Detail Application